# What is the 'reasonable' amount of time specified in many contracts in terms of working over the normal 'working day'?

Tags: management, work-time, law

In almost every single contract I have seen, there is this clause which allows the employers to request the contractor to work a 'reasonable' amount of hours when required beyond the normal work day (which I assume is 8 hours for most countries) without having to pay them more (in some cases they do as well).

I am a bit confused because from most of the labour laws I have seen there is a limitation on the number of hours that a person is allowed to work:

- Without a break
- With a break
- After having worked an extended period of time already

So how can it be 'reasonable' to request someone to work over a period of time without either:

- Providing them with a break as part of asking them to work an extended period of time
- Giving them a set amount of time off immediately after working this extended period
- Compensate them by payment of time worked or provide paid time off

Can someone provide an example of what the 'reasonable' amount of hours that was asked for, and how the employer justified the application of this clause?

Comment: This is company specific. The whole point of the weasel words are so that there isn't a hard number (or it would be specific).   The hope is you would need to go to court to decide if it was unreasonable,  something the vast majority wouldn't do.    Therefore off topic and voting to close I'm afraid.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager can't the answer be expressed as a proportion between the number of 'reasonable' hours and 'normal work day' in general? I know that different countries and companies have their own policies, but surely there's some common sense or rule of thumb around this?

Comment: There is no set rule.  Maybe local labour laws (or unions)  will put some kind of cap,  but that is regionally specific and this is a global site so we can't give an answer applicable everywhere.

Comment: It's like the similar clause about reasonable other duties.   What would that be,  answering phones? Moving furniture? Cleaning toilets?   It's about how far the employer will push and how far the employee will be pushed.

Comment: It just says they can request you to work more hours. If it is not reasonable, you should refuse (but perhaps find a new job first).

Comment: @MichaelLai: "Reasonable" will depend on the circumstances. There cannot be a fixed rule. If overtime is needed because the company is too tight to hire more people, 0 hours is reasonable. If overtime is needed because one guy left unexpectedly and the other guy broke a leg and cannot work, and there is work that absolutely needs to be done right now, then IMO any amount that the company compensates you for is reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

This is intentionally vague so that the company can use it when and if it needs to. There is no set rule. Many industries have set hours, a pilot cannot fly unless he has X amount of hours off within a 48 hour period and suchlike.

Rules like this are kept vague in case they need to push those limits, but they cannot overstep the legislated limits.

Each company would probably have it's own idea of what is 'reasonable' and probably this would change anytime it needed to for their convenience.

My general observation is that it means staying until the job is done if it's an urgent situation, usually with some sort of recompense. An example is when 3 out of 4 of a clients servers went down and I worked 30 hours straight getting them back in action, I wasn't expected to come in to work the next 2 days, but just to stay on call in case that particular client needed me.

Comment: I'd agree with this, but add that in the UK at least "Reasonable" is a legal term relating to what most people would consider acceptable/excessive. As such I'd also agree that it's vague, but that there are socially accepted norms: a couple of hours once a month on release day, and in the office until 10pm once or twice a year when something goes wrong, for example, would probably pass most people's "Okay, those are normal circumstances". Three hours every Thursday, on the other hand, probably wouldn't